# Why does `make_unique` use `new` while make_shared use `::new`

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, smart-pointers

I am working on a project where a couple of the classes overload operator `new` and `delete` to utilize free-lists and I tried to use `make_shared` to have my allocations managed by smart pointers when I realized that make_shared does not use the overloaded versions but makes an explicit call the global `::new`. But according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)  `make_unique` does use the overloaded versions. Which is quite baffling to me. Why does `make_shared` choose to ignore operator overloading but `make_unique` doesn't?

Comment: presumably because make_shared needs to additionally allocate the control block; make_unique just allocates the `T`.   Does make_shared not subsequently do a placement new?

Comment: https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`make_shared` has to allocate two things: the object being constructed and the `shared_ptr`'s control block.  To improve performance, it allocates one chunk of memory big enough for both and then placement-news them.

`make_unique` doesn't need to do that since a `unique_ptr` doesn't need a control block.

---

If you want to control how memory is allocated for an object to be managed by a `shared_ptr`, create an appropriate allocator class and use `allocate_shared` instead of `make_shared`.